# Collections for @Query params in Spring-Data? Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

How can I create a query which searches based on the IN clause? The documentation seems unclear? The following code compiles and runs, but the result set is not the expected nodes.

```
public interface SomeRepository extends GraphRepository<SomeNode> {

  @Query("START n=node({nodeid}) MATCH (n)-[r]-(p) WHERE p.id IN [{someids}] RETURN p")
  public Set<SomeNode> findByIds(@Param("nodeid") Long rootNodeId, @Param("someids") Set<Long> someIds);

}

@NodeEntity
public class SomeNode {

  @GraphId
  private Long internalId;

  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private Long id;

  // getters setters omitted.

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Without revisiting SDN, your `p.id` is your own id property, no? Distinct from Neo4j ID retrieved in cypher with `ID(p)`?

Comment: Yes.. id is a property of(in?) the node in this case. Not the ID of the node.

Comment: What do you mean by "the result set is not the expected nodes"? And can you show how you defined the id property, is it a different field from the @GraphId annotated id? Anyway, you could try removing the square brackets around the {someids}.

Comment: No results are returned when there are expected nodes.

After turning on debugging I am seeing the following query

START n=node({nodeid}) MATCH (n)-[r]-(p) WHERE p.id IN [{someids}] RETURN p params {someids=[1, 2], nodeid=1}

When I run the query in the neo4j, substituting the params in the actual inputs, I get the expected results..

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question (I think) but I solved this issue by adding a relation ship label and removing the [] around the IN statement. Turns out you don't need the [] and adding it caused the query to not return any results. Also I had nodes that were connected to node n that did not have an id value.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in your comment , you should remove the "[]" from your IN clause. A sample working Query in Spring-Data

```
@Query("MATCH (item:Item{id:{0}})-[:ALIGNS_TO]->(category:Category)
        ,(suggestItem:Item)-[:ALIGNS_TO]->(category)
        Where NOT(suggestItem.id IN {2})
        return suggestItem.id
        ORDER BY suggestItem.avg_rating DESC limit {1} ")

List<Integer> getCategoryItems( Integer itemId,int limit ,Set<Integer> excludeSet);
```